# Getting data from array of dictionaries in an array

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have created an `Array` of `Dictionaries`:

```
let tempArray = [["id":"1","Name":"ABC"],["id":"2","Name":"qwe"],["id":"3","Name":"rty"],["id":"4","Name":"uio"]]
```

Now I have to create an array of `Name` only.

What I have done is this:

```
var nameArray = [String]()
for dataDict in tempArray {
    nameArray.append(dataDict["Name"]!)
}
```

But is there any other efficient way of doing this.

Comment: try to implement getter setter so after adding data in array you can fetch the require data using loop or flap map as you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` (not `map`) for this, because `flatMap` can filter out `nil` values (case when dict doesn't have value for key "Name"), i.e. the `names` array will be defined as `[String]` instead of `[String?]`:

```
let tempArray = [["id":"1","Name":"ABC"],["id":"2","Name":"qwe"],["id":"3","Name":"rty"],["id":"4","Name":"uio"]]
let names = tempArray.flatMap({ $0["Name"] })
print(names) // ["ABC", "qwe", "rty", "uio"]
```

Comment: Thank you. your logic executed faster.

Answer (score 3):

Use `compactMap` as `flatMap` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907182-flatmap).

```
let tempArray = [["id":"1","Name":"ABC"],["id":"2","Name":"qwe"],["id":"3","Name":"rty"],["id":"4","Name":"uio"]]
let name = tempArray.compactMap({ $0["Name"]})
print(name)
```

[image]

Comment: @Cristik - With Xcode 9.3, Apple itself suggest replacing `flatMap` with `compactMap`. Although, you are right. Let check more detail and comparison between both, and hat should be better. Thanks for your remarks.